# Issue with focusin() and click()

Tags: jquery

what i want to achieve is

1. user types in textfield press tab or click next textfield results in removal of input tag replaced by displaying value read from text field  (WORKS)

   2.User clicks on this text result in going to edit mode ( textbox with value shown to edit or replace) (WORKS)

User clicks next text field or press tab which results in execution of step1 and so on (DOESNT WORK!)

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

     $("input#aoneonedata").focusout(function(){
     $(this).remove();
    var aoneone=parseInt($(this).val())||0;
    $(this).remove();
     $("#aoneone").append("<div id='a11'>"+aoneone+"x</div>");

      $("#a11").click(function(){
      $(this).remove();
    $("#aoneone").append("<input type='text'
    id='aoneonedata' value="+aoneone+">");
      });



      });


      });

     <table>
      <tr>
      <td id="aoneone"><input type="text" id="aoneonedata"></td>
      <td id="aonetwo"><input type="text" id="aonetwodata"></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Can you show html of 'next text field'?

Comment: If you're going to insist on usage of `table` tags for layout, at least use valid HTML and indent everything properly so it's easier to read and troubleshoot.  Same goes for your JavaScript.

Comment: you just bind event to `#aoneonedata`, are you missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats becouse you lose your `focusout` binding when you remove your input.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nescalante/c42A3/2/) fiddle.

If you strictly need to remove the input when you edit, try to reasign the function to `focusout` after recreating. But if you don't wont to reasign the `focusout` binding on each value change, you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Qr/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou fixed the issue , i have to double click to see blinking cursor for edit click event.Is there a fix?

Comment: add `$("input#aoneonedata").focus()` to set focus after creating the `input`

Comment: tried it. thankyou. last issue .focus() results in cursor set to first position of number in text field . is there a way to set it to last position of number in text field